# Python function exit does not work - why?

Tags: python

Why doesn't `exit()` stop the script after the first iteration?

In my opinion, it has to stop after the first iteration.

```
>>> def func(q):
...     def funct(y):
...         try:
...             print(y)
...             exit()
...         except:
...             pass
...     funct(q)
...
>>> a=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
>>> for x in a:
...     func(x)
...
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
>>>
```

Comment: @LydiavanDyke I see, I do not break the script, 'cause I have the exception. And `except` do nothing and script go on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question as directly as possible,

> Why doesn't `exit()` stop the script after the first iteration?

Because a bare `except` will catch `BaseException` and `Exception`, and since `exit()` raises a [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit), which is a `BaseException` subclass, your code will swallow the exception and pass on each iteration.

Note the difference if you catch `Exception` only, which does not suppress a `BaseException`:

```
>>> from sys import exit
>>> 
>>> def func(q):
...     def funct(y):
...         try:
...             print(y)
...             exit()
...         except Exception:
...             pass
...     funct(q)
... 
>>> a = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
>>> for x in a: func(x)
... 
1 # exits
```

Answer (score 2):

try: `sys.exit(0)` and move it to the scope of the global function

```
import sys 
def func(q):
    def funct(y):
        try:
            print(y)
        except:
             pass
    funct(q)
    sys.exit(0)

a=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
for x in a:
     func(x)

Output: 1
```